# Toggle (click) and bind event (on document)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I have a button `<a>` that should toggle a drop-down 
Then it should also bind (once) a click event to the document that when clicked it should slide it up.

I started with this HTML and JS...
Any suggestions how to make this work?

### HTML

```
      <a class="a" href="#">continue shopping</a>
      <div class="b">
        <a href="#">continue 1</a>
        <a href="#">continue 2</a>
        <a href="#">continue 3</a>
        <a href="#">continue 4</a>
      </div>
```

### JS

```
 $(".a").toggle(function(event){
   buttonEvent = $(event.target)
    $(this).addClass("open").next(".a").slideDown(500);

    $(document).one("click",function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is(".a") && !buttonEvent.hasClass("b")){
        $(".b").slideUp(500)
     }  
  })

 },
 function(){
  $(this).removeClass("open").next(".continueShopCntnr").slideUp(500)
});
```

But it is still buggy..  when clicked on again on the continue shopping it doesn't do nothing

Comment: Do you realize that using a hash (#) in the href attribute of the <a/> tag makes it refresh the page? Not sure if this is standard practice in Jquery, but for regular Javascript using href="javascript:void(0)" or href="javascript://" is cleaner and leaves no unwanted footprint.

Comment: thanks, No, that is not my problem, yea ill add a return false.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would work better... it closes any open ones on the document click.

EDIT: Actually tested this code (vs the previous answer) and it works as I understand the requirements.

```
$(".continueShop").toggle(
    function(){
      $(this).removeClass("open").next(".continueShopCntnr").slideUp(500)
    },
    function(){
        $(this).addClass("open").next(".continueShopCntnr").slideDown(500);

        $(document).one("click",function() {
           $(".continueShop.open").each(function() { 
               $(this).click();
           });
         });
     }
);
```

Comment: when clicking on the continueShop once it slidesUp and slidesDown

Comment: I revised the code above.  See if it works for you.  It's working for me in my little test app.  I also switched the toggle function since when the page loads the dialog is already open (at least from the html sample you included) so the first click would close it instead of open it. And I removed the return false because looking at the jQuery docs for toggle it says it already does preventDefault() for you.